# Status Bar hides out when view presented Modally in UINavigationController

Tags: ios7, statusbar

I have a NavigationController based small app using storyboard, when i am presenting view modally it hides the status bar completely which i dont want , I have searched enough but no simple solution for this i could find, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok either that was silly enough or I just missed it out
I had to change following method in the same view controller

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Changed UiStatusBarStyle to Default and its now visible this happened as my view had white background and the style was set to lightContent.